# Get events from mySQL. PHP calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Im trying to get get a calendarscript to connect to mySQL database. The script is a simple calendarpicker witch I am trying to connect to a database so it can display events. 
I managed to get the event I have in my database displaying for all days in the month, but I would like it to display as a link only for the day it is set. I would also like to add a function for adding and deleting events, but first thing first.

My database looks like this:

```
database: calendar

table: calendar_events
row1: event_title
row2: event_shortdesc
row3: event_start
```

This is my entire code for the script, the calendarfunction works fine.

```
<?php include("includes/header.php")?>
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php")?>
<?php include("includes/functions.php")?>

<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("m"); 
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y"); 

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"]; 
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"]; 

$prev_year = $cYear; 
$next_year = $cYear; 
$prev_month = $cMonth-1; 
$next_month = $cMonth+1; 

if ($prev_month == 0) {
    $prev_month = 12; 
    $prev_year = $cYear-1; 
}

if ($next_month == 13) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear+1;  
}

$monthNames = Array("Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli",
"August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"); 

?>

<div id="kalendercontainer">

<a id="prev" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>">Previous</a>

<span id="monthname"><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></span>

<a id="next" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>">Next</a> 

<table id="kalender">

<tr>
<td><strong>Man</strong></td>
<td><strong>Tir</strong></td>
<td><strong>Ons</strong></td>
<td><strong>Tor</strong></td>
<td><strong>Fre</strong></td>
<td><strong>Lør</strong></td>
<td><strong>Søn</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday']-1;


//Get calendar events

$get_cal_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar_events WHERE event_start = '{$startday}'"); 

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($get_cal_events); 

$event = $rows['event_title'] . $rows['event_shortdesc']; 


//Draw calendar

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {          

    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";

    else 

    echo "<td>" . ($event) . ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}                   

?>
</table>
<p></p>
</div> 

<?php require("includes/footer.php")?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the cell day against the event day before echoing `$event`. Make the following 2 changes to `//Get calendar events` and `//Draw Calendar`. The changes are at `//ADD THIS CODE`.

This assumes that `event_start` is a date (ie 2012-09-17).

```
//Get calendar events

$get_cal_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar_events WHERE event_start = '{$startday}'"); 

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($get_cal_events); 

$event = $rows['event_title'] . $rows['event_shortdesc']; 

//ADD THIS CODE
// Gets the event day. Assuming the event_start is a mysql date (ie. 2012-09-17) 
$event_day = date("j", strtotime($rows['event_start']));


//Draw calendar

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {          

if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";

else 

echo "<td>";
    //ADD THIS CODE
    // Checks to see if the event day is the same as the cell day
    if ($event_day == ($i - $startday + 1)) echo $event;
echo ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get this to work. It makes the first day of the calendar display  **if ($event_day == ($i - $startday + 1)) echo $event;**  (I added a div element with red background to this to see if it turned up) a red div, but no event. No matter if it was a event(s) or not in the database.  The event_start is set to "date" in mySQL,

Comment: First, make sure the line before ends with `";` as that is one of the only reasons `if ($event_day == ($i - $startday + 1)) echo $event;` would be echoed out directly . It should be run with all other php.
Second, you may need to look at how you are using `$startday` in your MySQL query `"SELECT * FROM calendar_events WHERE event_start = '{$startday}'"`. When I ran your code using September 2012 it set `$startday` = 5, so the query would would be `WHERE event_start = 5`, which would make it echo out on the first day of the month, which is currently 5, instead of the correct day of the event.

Comment: The line before has the correct ending, so I dont know why it is not working. I'll try to look into the **$startday** variable and see if I can get it to work, thanks for helping!